# i am implementing winwheel in my angular 7 project, but nothing is displayed, whats wrong?

Tags: angular

I am implementing winwheel from here
http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_code_wheel
in my angular V7.2.0 project, but just blank screen is displayed on view, only power and spin button is visible and wheel is blank. is this the problem of due to canvas? Please help me on implementing the wheel.

Comment: Email doug the creator of winwheel he will respond and is helpful if he can be.

Answer (score 1):

http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs

It has step by step tutorial. 
First thing is importing the .js in your component file.

What I did is imported it at angular.json file, under

```js
"script":['src/assets/Winwheel.js']
```

, in your component.ts file, right after the import codes, add this line of code:

```js
declare let Winwheel: any
```